# Generating text file after retrieving records from SQL Server using SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence

I need guidelines to do a task. I am new to work in SSIS & I only its very basics. But I can try to do it myself if someone guides me to choose the appropriate tools & how to do it. The task I've divided in to series of steps. Please help me to create this project

Step 1: retrieve Employee_ID's from a table in SQL Server

```
select disctinct(employee_id) 
from emp_details
```

Step 2: retrieve attendance details from another table for every `employee_id` retrieved in the previous step.

```
select * from emp_attendance 
where employee_id = ....
```

Step 3: write all the records retrieved to a text file. The name of the text file should be the employee id.

For ex: for employee id 1234, a file should be generated in the specified path with the file name 1234.txt with that employee's attendance details inside it. I.e the records retrieved from step 2 Inside it.

How can I achieve this task? What all tools must I use & what is the logic. Plz guide me friends.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: This pretty much exactly describes what you want to do: http://www.timmitchell.net/post/2013/05/28/using-the-ssis-object-variable-as-a-result-set-enumerator/ Have a go yourself and post back any specific errors.

Comment: You are the man  Thats exactly what I was looking for. If any specific errors i will get back. Thanks 

Comment: For the flat file destination im unable to see connection string property and use variables :-(

Comment: These properties can be edited in the 'Connection Manager' area, not against the actual flat file itself. Go to the bottom of the screen, find your flat file connection manager then go to properties on the right and click 'expressions'. Not the properties window is sensitive - you need to click in the right spot for the correct properties to appear.

Comment: Ya thank you so much. I got it & i did it. Its perfectly working. Thanks a lot 

Comment: OK I'm going to summarise the approach as an answer (as links are not really good enough for an answer) and you you may or may not accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a summary of the solution in the posted link:

1. Use a SQL Task to populate a SSIS object variable with a recordset containing the list of employee_is
2. Iterate through the object variable using a for each ADO enumerator
3. In the for each ADO enumerator, map the employee_id column in your SSIS object variable to individual a string or integer SSIS variable called employee_id
4. Inside the for each ADO enumerator, use a data flow task to transfer data from the DB to a text file
5. Use the employee_id column mapped in step 3 as a parameter in your source SQL in step 4 to limit the dataset to a single employee for each iteration
6. Use the employee_id column mapped in step 3 in an expression in your file connection manager to dynamically build the output file name